# How to enable full column width in Genesis layout options

Tags: genesis-theme-framework

We are running Genesis Framework version 1.6 on our site and cannot figure out how to enable the full column width option. Where do you go to enable this layout option?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking to set the entire site full-width or a page?

You should have an option like this under Genesis > Theme Options:

http://cl.ly/3i2n3j2e2s1p0q1N2q3Z

For a page, you can find the same options under the visual editor.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was looking for, however I figured it out. The original developer put the control in a different file than expected. Thanks.